# How set rtl for grid values in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs6.5

I'm developing a form using ExtJS which contains a grid and one of its columns usually has a negative value so there is a problem in displaying negative sign before the number and it will be shown as 1234567- !! Infact value of the record in its renderer is in right way but displaying is reverse!

I tried to set direction or set "rtl" for this column but it just works on the header of the grid.

How should I change my code to fix it?

Comment: To clarify, is your app running in RTL mode?

Comment: yes, it's a website in Persian language so all of its parts are RTL.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should change in app.json.

```
Change "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js"
For "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-all-debug.js"
```

and do sencha app watch. I think it will be work